# Tax write-off for research-related expenses in the US?

Tags: united-states, travel, fees

I am wondering if any research-related expenses can be applied toward a personal tax write-off (in the U.S.).  For example, assume I traveled to a conference or meeting to present my research, and all the expenses were paid out-of-pocket.  Or, assume that I purchase some equipment or supplies that is used for my research.  Does a provision in the tax code exist that would allow the expenses to be considered a tax write off?  If so, a link to the IRS rule would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not a lawyer and this is not legal/tax advice.

I believe you can deduct these as *unreimbursed employee expenses*.  For 2013, this was Line 21 of Form 1040 Schedule A.  Details can be found in [IRS Pub. 529](http://www.irs.gov/publications/p529/index.html).  It lists a number of examples of expenses that would be deductible on this line, including:

- Research expenses of a college professor
- Travel related to your work
- Tools and supplies used in your work
- Subscriptions to professional journals
- Dues to professional societies

There are a couple of major caveats:

- Roughly, you can only deduct the amount that exceeds 2% of your adjusted gross income (AGI).  More specifically, you take the amount of your *unreimbursed employee expenses*, add the rest of your *miscellaneous itemized deductions* if any (see Pub. 529 for the list), and subtract 2% of your AGI; you can deduct the difference.  So this may only apply if your research expenses are fairly substantial, or you have other significant *miscellaneous itemized deductions*.  (Note that *miscellaneous itemized deductions* do not include the big itemized deductions like charitable donations, state taxes, or mortgage interest.)
- You have to itemize deductions to do this.  If you don't have many other itemized deductions, you may be better off just taking the standard deduction.
- Of course, you cannot deduct expenses that were reimbursed.

Note that you might also get good answers on http://money.stackexchange.com.